# Cakephp4, how to load associated data in an Entity object?

Tags: cakephp, entity, associated-value

I have a Users table and a Roles table.
A user has one role. So in UsersTable.php:

```
   $this->belongsTo('Roles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
```

Now in User.php (Entity!!) I need the role name of the users role.
But I have only the User Entity in which is no associated data.
I now have:

```
    public function getRole()
    {
        $q = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Roles');
        $roles = $q->find('list')->toArray();
        return $roles[$this->role_id];
    }
```

This works, but TableRegistry is marked obsolete in cake4, and I can't find any other way the make this work. What is the propper way of doing this?

Comment: You really should do the basic tutorials https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples.html and read these two pages https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html & https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/associations.html You haven't understood the ORM in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use both the User and Role data in a controller you can just do for example

```
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Roles'],
    ]);
```

and the resulting object has `$user->role` defined as a `Role` entity.

However, I have a feeling you already know this and have another issue that may or may not overlap with a problem I was solving just recently. Check out ndm's answer to my question here and hopefully it helps you! [CakePHP 4.1 User entity as authorization identity associated fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057543/cakephp-4-1-user-entity-as-authorization-identity-associated-fields)

Apologies if that's not your scenario, I just found this current thread while looking for an answer to my problem, and it was definitely the closest to my own issue.

Comment: Your question was a much better descriptions of my problem. I found an similar solution. Adding the finder in the userTable was the key!