# CakePHP 4.1 User entity as authorization identity associated fields

Tags: cakephp, orm, entity, cakephp-4.x

I have just created a very minimal project in CakePHP 4.1, mostly mimicking the CMS tutorial, and want to implement a fairly straightforward piece of logic.
Using the `Authorization` module I want to allow a user `A` to be able to `view` a user `B` if 1) they are actually the same user (`A = B`) OR 2) if `A` is an admin.

There are two DB tables - `users` and `user_types`. `users` has a foreign key `user_type_id` to `user_types`.

This relationship is reflected in code as:

```
##### in UsersTable.php #####

class UsersTable extends Table {
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->belongsTo('UserTypes');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }

    //...
}



##### in UserTypesTable.php #####

class UserTypesTable extends Table {
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('user_types');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->hasMany('Users');
    }

    //...
}
```

In `UsersController.php` I have:

```
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['UserTypes'],
        ]);

        $this->Authorization->authorize($user);

        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }
```

And in `UserPolicy.php`:

```
use App\Model\Entity\User;

class UserPolicy
{
    public function canView(User $user, User $resource)
    {
        // TODO: allow view if $user and $resource are the same User or if $user is an admin
        //
        // My problem is that here $user->user_type is NULL
        // while $resource->user_type is populated correctly
    }
}
```

The code comment in the above excerpt shows where my problem is.
I do not know how to get `$user` to have its `user_type` field populated in order to check whether they're an admin.

As a part of my efforts, I have set the User class to be the authorization identity, following this article: https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/middleware.html#using-your-user-class-as-the-identity.
Code-wise this looks like:

```
##### relevant part of Application.php #####

$middlewareQueue
            ->add(new AuthenticationMiddleware($this))
            ->add(new AuthorizationMiddleware($this, [
                'identityDecorator' => function(\Authorization\AuthorizationServiceInterface $auth, \Authentication\IdentityInterface $user) {
                    return $user->getOriginalData()->setAuthorization($auth);
                }
            ]));





##### User.php #####

namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Authentication\PasswordHasher\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Authorization\AuthorizationServiceInterface;
use Authorization\Policy\ResultInterface;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * User Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property string|null $name
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\UserType $user_type
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime|null $created
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime|null $modified
 * @property \Authorization\AuthorizationServiceInterface $authorization
 */
class User extends Entity implements \Authorization\IdentityInterface, \Authentication\IdentityInterface
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'email' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'name' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true,
    ];

    /**

    protected $_hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    protected function _setPassword(string $password) : ?string
    {
        if (strlen($password) > 0) {
            return (new DefaultPasswordHasher())->hash($password);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function can(string $action, $resource): bool
    {
        return $this->authorization->can($this, $action, $resource);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function canResult(string $action, $resource): ResultInterface
    {
        return $this->authorization->canResult($this, $action, $resource);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function applyScope(string $action, $resource)
    {
        return $this->authorization->applyScope($this, $action, $resource);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getOriginalData()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setter to be used by the middleware.
     * @param AuthorizationServiceInterface $service
     * @return User
     */
    public function setAuthorization(AuthorizationServiceInterface $service)
    {
        $this->authorization = $service;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

However, I have not been able to get the identity `User` in the `UserPolicy.php` file to have the `user_type` field populated.
Some under-the-hood magic seems to happen when I call `$this->Authorization->authorize()` from the controller where I explicitly pass the resource together with its user type (since I have constructed it with `'contain' => ['UserTypes']` BUT the identity user is populated automatically by the `Authorization` module.
Could someone please help me to find a way to bring associated tables data into the identity user of an authorization policy?

NOTE:
I have fudged the code to make it work like this:

```
##### in UserPolicy.php #####


use App\Model\Entity\User;

class UserPolicy
{
    public function canView(User $user, User $resource)
    {
        $user = \Cake\Datasource\FactoryLocator::get('Table')->get('Users')->get($user->id, ['contain' => ['UserTypes']]);

        // Now both $user->user_type and $resource->user_type are correctly populated
    }
}
```

HOWEVER, this feels awfully "hacky" and not the way it's supposed to be, so my original question still stands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The identity is being obtained by the resolver of the involved identifier. In case of the CMS tutorial that's the `Password` identifier which by default uses the `ORM` resolver.

The `ORM` resolver can be configured to use a custom finder in case you need to control the query for obtaining the user, that's where you should add the containment for your `UserTypes` association.

In your `UsersTable` add a finder like this:

```php
public function findForAuthentication(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options): \Cake\ORM\Query
{
    return $query->contain('UserTypes');
}
```

and configure the identifier's resolver to use that finder like this:

```php
$service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
    'resolver' => [
        'className' => 'Authentication.Orm',
        'finder' => 'forAuthentication',
    ],
    'fields' => [
        'username' => 'email',
        'password' => 'password',
    ]
]);
```

You need to specify the resolver class name too when overriding the `resolver` option, as by default it is just a string, not an array that would merge with the new config!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**
- **[Authentication Cookbook > Identifiers](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/identifiers.html)**