# CakePHP: Login over 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, cakephp

I have a CakePHP website that has a new database structure and I want to reconfigure the login. First of all this is my error `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Users.email' in 'where clause'`.

I have 2 Tables which are connected over the `UUID` field.

| Users | Userdata |
| --- | --- |
| ID | ID |
| UUID | UUID |
| password | email |

In the old website, the email and password were in the same table but not now. I have created the Table / Entitys with the plugin bake. Finally I have set `$this->hasOne('Userdata');` on UsersTable.php and `$this->hasOne('Users');` in the UserdataTable.php.

UserdataTable.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UserdataTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('userdata');
        $this->setDisplayField('ID');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('ID');
        $this->hasOne('Users');
    }
}
```

UserTable.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setDisplayField('ID');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('ID');
        $this->hasOne('Userdata');
    }
}
```

This is in my AppController.php

```
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize'=> 'Controller',
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
             //use isAuthorized in Controllers
            'authorize' => ['Controller'],
             // If unauthorized, return them to page they were just on
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
        ]);
```

and then in my UsersController.php

```
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
        }
    }
```

Im using CakePHP Version 3.6.15

Comment: This is all good info, but you'll also need to share how your application handles authentication/login, as that is where the relevant magic happens. Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question and added App/UsersController and the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is a custom finder so that you can modify the query that is used to look up the user record.

The most simple, and most fordward compatible way would probably be to simply contain the `Userdata` association in the query, and configure the form authenticator's `username` option to include the alias, eg `Userdata.email` instead of just `email`.

In your `UsersTable` class:

```php
public function findWithUserdata(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options): \Cake\ORM\Query
{
    return $query->contain('Userdata');
}
```

In your `Auth` component config:

```php
'authenticate' => [
    'Form' => [
        'fields' => [
            'username' => 'Userdata.email', // << this one here
            'password' => 'password'
        ],
        'finder' => 'withUserData', // << and that one
    ]
],
```

This should then give you a lookup query along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    users Users
LEFT JOIN
    userdata Userdata ON Userdata.UUID = Users.UUID
WHERE
    Userdata.email = 'some@email.address'
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > AuthComponent > Configuring Authentication Handlers](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > AuthComponent > Customizing Find Query](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**

Comment: Have many thanks. Sad thing is that I had to start with the 4.x version where its not working anymore. I will make a new thread. (Your solution worked for 3.x)

Comment: @thedoomer1000 The finder and fields aliases should still work, you just configure things in a different place now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057543/cakephp-4-1-user-entity-as-authorization-identity-associated-fields/63061706#63061706